# wagtail svg in html template not rendering

Tags: html, django, wagtail

Seems like such a basic question but I have put wagtails svg uploader into a separate block outside of the body, everything working as it should but when I save and preview nothing is showing up?

In my model:

```
svg_img = models.ForeignKey(
      Svg,
      related_name='+',
      null=True,
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
      blank=True
  )

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    SvgChooserPanel('svg_img'),
]
```

As for the HTML:

```
{% if page.svg_img %}
    <li>
        <h4>Origin</h4>
        {{ page.svg_img }}
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

It returns None even though I have uploaded an svg? Any Ideas anyone?

Comment: Wagtail does not have an SVG uploader or anything named SvgChooserPanel. Are you using a third-party add-on package?

Comment: Hi gasman, I have followed the instructions using a third party package https://pypi.org/project/wagtailsvg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{{ self.svg_img.url }}` to get **url** and then add to your template:

```
<svg>
    <use href="{{ self.svg_img.url }}#class-o"></use>
</svg>
```

OR

```
<img src="{{ self.image.url }}">
```